# How to provide context from contextApi for a specific set of routes in nextjs and preserve state with routing through linking?

Tags: reactjs, state, next.js, react-context

I am using contextApi with nextjs and I'm having some trouble when providing a context just for certain routes. I am able to make the context available for just a few routes, but when I transition from one to the other through linking, I end up losing the state of my application.

I have three files inside my pages folder:
`index.tsx`,
`Dashboard/index.tsx` and
`SignIn/index.tsx`.

If I import the provider inside the files `Dashboard/index.tsx` and `SignIn/index.tsx` and go from one page to the other by pressing a Link component from `next/link`, the whole state is set back to the initial state.

The content of the `Dashboard/index.tsx` file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Dashboard from '../../app/views/Dashboard';
    import { AuthProvider } from '../../contexts/auth';
    const Index: React.FC = () => (
      <AuthProvider>
        <Dashboard />
      </AuthProvider>
    );
    export default Index;
```

This is the contend of the `SignIn/index.tsx` file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import SignIn from '../../app/views/SignIn';
    import { AuthProvider } from '../../contexts/auth';
    const Index: React.FC = () => (
      <AuthProvider>
        <SignIn />
      </AuthProvider>
    );
    export default Index;
```

The views folder is where I create the components that will be rendered.
The content of the file `views/SignIn/index.tsx` is:

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import { AuthContext } from '../../../contexts/auth';
    const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
      const { signed, signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
      async function handleSignIn() {
        signIn();
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Link href="Dashboard">Go back to Dashboard</Link>
          <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Click me</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default SignIn;
```

And the content of the file `views/Dashboard/index.tsx` is:

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import { AuthContext } from '../../../contexts/auth';
    const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
      const { signed, signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
      async function handleSignIn() {
        signIn();
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Link href="SignIn">Go back to sign in page</Link>
          <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Click me</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default Dashboard;
```

I am able to access the context inside both `/Dashboard` and `/SignIn`, but when I press the link, the state comes back to the initial one. I figured out that the whole provider is rerenderized and therefore the new state becomes the initial state, but I wasn't able to go around this issue in a "best practices manner".

If I put the provider inside `_app.tsx`, I can maintain the state when transitioning between pages, but I end up providing this state to the `/` route as well, which I am trying to avoid.

I was able to go around this by doing the following, but it really does not seem to be the best solution for me.

I removed the Providers from `Pages/SignIn/index.tsx` and `Pages/Dashboard/index.tsx` and used the following snippet for the `_app.tsx` file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
    import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/auth';
    const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
      const router = useRouter();
      const AuthProviderRoutes = ['/SignIn', '/Dashboard'];
      return (
        <>
          {AuthProviderRoutes.includes(router.pathname) ? (
            <AuthProvider>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AuthProvider>
          ) : <Component {...pageProps} />}
        </>
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Hi @andré-guimarães-aragon! Have you managed to find a solution for this question?

Comment: Hi! Yes I did find it, I came up with a solution myself actually. Since you asked about it, I will try to post it tomorrow.

Comment: Nice! Would be nice to see how you did that, yes :)

Comment: I had the same problem and implemented your very same ad-hoc fix haha. I'm curious to see the alternative solution you mentioned...

Comment: same here! commenting here to get updated if there's a better solution. @AndréGuimarãesAragon thanks for you alternative solution! it works wonders